# How to find out which version of the .NET Framework an executable needs to run?

Tags: .net, version, executable

I've got an executable file, and I would like to know which version(s) of the Microsoft .NET Framework this file needs to be started.

Is there an easy way to find this information somewhere?

(So far I tried [ILDASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILDASM#Metadata_storage) and [DUMPBIN](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) without any luck.)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460982/determine-net-framework-version-for-dll?tab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/ -- Process Explorer does this very well and easy to use, just run it as admin

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think the closest you can reliably get is to determine what version of the **CLR** is required. You can do this by using ILDASM and looking at the "MANIFEST" node or Reflector and looking at the dissasembly view of the "Application.exe" node as IL. In both cases there is a comment that indicates the CLR version. In ILDASM, the comment is "// Metadata version" and in Reflector the comment is "Target Runtime Version".

Here are examples for a .NET WinForms application named WindowsFormsApplication1.exe:

ILDASM:

```
// Metadata version: v2.0.50727
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern System
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
```

Reflector:

```
.module WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
.subsystem 0x0002
// MVID: {CA3D2090-16C5-4899-953E-4736D6BC0FA8}
// Target Runtime Version: v2.0.50727
```

You can also look at the list of referenced assemblies and look for the reference with the highest version number.

Again, using ILDASM looking at the "MANIFEST" node data:

```
.assembly extern System.Drawing
{
  .publickeytoken = (B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A )                         // .?_....:
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern System.Core
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 3:5:0:0
}
```

And using Reflector, looking at the dissambly (still as IL) for each reference listed:

```
.assembly extern System.Core
{
    .ver 3:5:0:0
    .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89)
}
```

By finding the reference with the highest version metadata you can determine what version of the Framework that reference came from, which would indicate that you need the same version of the Framework installed for the application to run. That being said, I wouldn't treat this as 100% reliable, but I don't think it will change any time soon.

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft introduces a breaking change for the above technique. .NET 4.5 assemblies cannot run on raw .NET 4, and to tell a .NET 4.5 assembly you need to also read System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute. http://www.lextm.com/2013/02/how-to-tell-net-45-only-assemblies.html

Comment: @LexLi link does not work

Comment: @Zoli https://halfblood.pro/how-to-tell-net-4-5-only-assemblies-f5e9041533bb

Answer (score 89):

Using [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Notepad), three decades old, 200kb in size, preinstalled tool:

- open application with `notepad appname.exe`,
- search for word `framework`,
- repeat last search with `F3` until `.NET Framework,version=vX.Y` shows up
- if nothing found (versions below 3.0) search for `v2.` ... still 100 times easier then installing gigabytes of dot net analyzer tools and garbage studios.

**update:** Thought and Marcus suggested in comments that search term could also be `netstandard` or `netframework`

Comment: This is great- especially if you don't have access to decompile/other tools

Comment: Update:  It may not be found, and instead there may be a ".NETStandard,version=..."

Comment: Update: on an app I've just verified, the string does not include the space: `.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2`

Comment: My .exe (winforms) has zero string of any of the above

Answer (score 37):

A more simplified approach would be to use [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and see what shows up in the tree.

See the properties panel:
[image]

Answer (score 27):

You can now use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to examine the target framework of an assembly.  After loading the assembly, click on the root of the assembly node, and you can find the information under the TargetFramework declaration:

```
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.5", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.5")]
```

Comment: Note that [TargetFrameworkAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.versioning.targetframeworkattribute) was only added in .NET 4.0, so will not be present on assemblies compiled against .NET 3.5 or earlier.

Comment: ILSpy shows "Runtime: vXXX" in comments when clicking the loaded assembly root node. I was able to see a v1.1.4322 framework project.

Comment: It shows me:
`// Architecture: x64
// Runtime: .NET 4.0
`

Answer (score 16):

From the command line: `find "Framework" MyApp.exe`

Comment: Note: it's case-sensitive, "findframework" (lower f) will not work.

Comment: Does not work. All I get as result for my WinForms .exe: `PresentationFramework`

Answer (score 15):

From code you can use [`Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.imageruntimeversion.aspx) but by looking at the file probably the best thing to do would be to use reflector and see which version of `mscorlib` is being referenced.

**Edit:**  Even better would be to use [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387(VS.71).aspx), open your assembly and then view the manifest for the assembly.  The first line of the manifest will tell you the *exact* version of CLR that the assembly was built for.

Comment: This is wrong. The OP asked about the version of .NET Framework, not the version of the CLR Runtime. This answer address the latter. As an example, I am running against Framework 4.7.2531.0 which uses the CLR Runtime version 4.0.30139. ImageRuntimeVersion returns the CLR version, not the Framework version.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a tool called CorFlags.exe.  It has been around since .NET 2.0, and I know for sure that it is included in the Windows SDK 7.0.  By default (on Windows XP Pro) it is installed to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\CorFlags.exe.  Provide it with the file path to a managed module (without any other command-line flags) to display its header information, which includes the version.

Keep in mind that this utility is designed to modify the PE32 header of a module, so don't use any of the flags until you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) carefully.

Comment: Cannot distinguish between .Net4 and .Net4.5

Answer (score 6):

You can obtain the .NET version of a file in Windows using Powershell.  The following script;

```
$path=’.\’
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$files=Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -include *.dll,*.exe
foreach($file in $files)
{
    $filename = $file.BaseName
    $version = $([System.Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom($file.FullName).GetCustomAttributesData() |
                 select-object -ExpandProperty ConstructorArguments | 
                 select-object -ExpandProperty Value | 
                 select-string -Pattern '.NET')
    Write-Output "$filename,$version"
}
```

provides the following result;
[image]

Note that the result extracted the .NET version for the exe files in that folder, but it will also do the same for a dll.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I copied and pasted everything into powershell with my path altered to the exe path and it just tells me the name of the application, nothing else

Comment: Nicely done; to make it work in PowerShell _Core_, replace `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` with `LoadFile`

Comment: Same for me, says nothing about my Winforms exe, only the filename printed

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just find out which reference of System.Core it has. That will tell you the .NET Framework version this app is using. For 2.0 the version of System.Core will be 2.0.xxx.xxx. For 3.5 the version will be 3.5.xxx.xxx, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I have a target framework of 4.5 but use System.Core 4.0.XXX.XXX

Answer (score 2):

On Linux/OSX/unix you can use:

```
strings that_app.exe | grep 'v2.\|Framework'
```

Answer (score 1):

For newer .NET 6.0 applications the notepad method did not work for me, but if there is a *.deps.json file next to the exes that's a big clue - often contains the version in form of the following section

```
"runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0/win-x86"
```

Edit: following up, you can also look for a pair of .exe and .dll files with the same name, try opening the DLL file in notepad and search for **NETCoreApp**, you should find something like this:

```
.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open ILSpy: Launch the ILSpy application on your computer.
2. Open EXE in ILSpy: Use the "File" menu or a similar option to open
   the EXE file within ILSpy. This action allows you to decompile and
   view the contents of the executable.
3. Select the Root Entry: In  ILSpy select top entry.
4. View Left-Hand Side Pane: After selecting the top entry or any other
   part of the code, you should see details about that element in the
   left-hand side pane. This may include information about the
   assembly.
5. Check Version Name: In the left-hand side pane, there may be
   information about the version of the assembly. Look for a section
   that provides details like the assembly version, file version, or
   product version.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEq5A.png)