# Find which framework is required?

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out which version of the .NET Framework an executable needs to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325918/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-the-net-framework-an-executable-needs-to-run)

Suppose I'm provided with a Windows .Net binary: Is there a way to know which version of the .Net framework it needs to run?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325918/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-the-net-framework-an-executable-needs-to-run

Answer (score 0):

You can open it in dotPeek. Look at where it is placed in the tree or look the references required.

Comment: this was already posted at the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325918/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-the-net-framework-an-executable-needs-to-run/7889683#7889683

Comment: @DanielA.White: I know. And I saw it then too.