# How to find the .NET version for a DLL

Tags: .net, frameworks

I have a couple of third party DLLs and suspect that they're causing issues as they're written using the latest .NET framework.

Could someone please suggest what the best way of finding out the .NET version that a DLL is written on is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out which version of the .NET Framework an executable needs to run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325918/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-the-net-framework-an-executable-needs-to-run)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  MSIL Disassembler (ildasm.exe) to view the manifest information which contains the version used. Here is a link with instructions:

http://geekswithblogs.net/gpro/archive/2008/08/27/determine-.net-framework-version-of-an-application.aspx

Comment: That's not a convenient way, especially when .NET 4 and .NET 4.5 assemblies are almost the same (except a few attributes).

Answer (score 0):

A good enough decompiler should show you the expected runtime version of an assembly,

http://www.lextm.com/2013/02/how-to-tell-net-45-only-assemblies.html

As I wrote in the blog post, JustDecompile is one of such decompilers. For ILSpy, it needs to be patched to distinguish .NET 4 and 4.5.