# Determining the target environment of a .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, windows-ce

Visual Studio 2008 can produce assembly that target the .NET 3.5 Compact Framework for Windows CE.
Is there an easy way in C# perhaps using reflection or mono cecil to determine what environment a given DLL targets.

Comment: Do you mean "what it targets" or "what it is currently running in"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325918/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-the-net-framework-an-executable-needs-to-run

Comment: Barely.  It will reference mscorlib version 3.5.0.0.  That's unique for .NET CF assemblies afaik.