# Importing DLL into Unity - Type or namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, dll, unity-game-engine, import

I'm working on a project using a USB interface device (see [here](http://www.velleman.eu/support/downloads/?code=K8055)), and trying to use the DLL provided in the SDK pack within my Unity application. The end goal is to allow Unity to access inputs and outputs from the hardware - functionality for this is provided by the DLL.

[I added the DLL to the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEeSh.jpg), and tried to access it from a script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using k8055d;

public class DLLTest01 : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public k8055d usbHandler;

    void Start(){}
}
```

Unity threw me an error. The error was:

> Assets/Resources/Scripts/DLLTest01.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name `k8055d' could not be found. Are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?

The DLL is definitely within the project's folder, and named 'k8055d.dll', what could be the cause of this and what can I do to get the DLL working with any games I happen to make for my hardware device?

I feel like this may have something to do with the .NET version that Unity is using but I'm not sure what I can do if that's the issue.

Comment: The DLL is compatible with .NET 3.5?

Comment: How do I check that??

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325918/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-the-net-framework-an-executable-needs-to-run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the docs and your DLL is not a .NET one. It is compiled, so you'll need to use a Plugin to be able to use it with Unity3D. (You'll probably need to create a .NET wrapper around that native dll code.)

[Documentation about how to create plugins is available at the Unity Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this :)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/458300/how-to-use-a-external-dll.html) from the unity forums should help you:

> To use an external DLL in your game, just place it inside of your Unity Project, in the Assets directory. Then, next time Unity synchronizes Visual Studio/MonoDevelop project, it'll add the necessary references to the DLLs in your Visual Studio/MonoDevelop project.

So, try placing the DLL in your `Assets` directory and see if that does it!

You could also try using DllImport, like so:

```
[DllImport("k8055d.dll")]
```

But as you say in your question it could very well be a .NET version issue.

Comment: Hi Micah, see if my edit helps you. Otherwise, I'll have to try it myself at home later :)

Comment: Unfortunately, using DLLImport just threw me this error instead. Assets/Resources/Scripts/DLLTest01.cs(6,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `DllImport' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I'm happy to wait until you get home :)

Comment: No worries. I think you might need `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` for DLLImport, does that help?

Comment: Ahh sweet, that makes sense. I'm now getting this error, however: Assets/Resources/Scripts/DLLTest01.cs(7,10): error CS0601: The DllImport attribute must be specified on a method marked `static' and `extern'

Comment: Okay, might not be that then. By the way, which folder do you have the DLL in? Try putting it in the `Plugins` folder, with and without the `DllImport`, and see if that does it.