# How to check the version of .NET Core in a deployed app?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to interrogate the version of the .NET Core that my web app was compiled with.  The app is deployed on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Linux 4.9.28-v7+ armv7l.  Not seeing an obvious way to do it.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but might be related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325918/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-the-net-framework-an-executable-needs-to-run

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet:

```
var framework = Assembly
    .GetEntryAssembly()?
    .GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>()?
    .FrameworkName;

var stats = new
{                
    OsPlatform = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSDescription,
    AspDotnetVersion = framework
};
```

Code found on: [weblog.west-wind.com](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Apr/12/Getting-the-NET-Core-Runtime-Version-in-a-Running-Application)

When run on my pc it returns:

```
Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134 
.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1
```

Comment: The app is already deployed.  I need to interrogate the deployed app - source can't be changed.

Comment: If you have access to the dll files you can load on of those assemblies. Instead of calling `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` you call 'Assembly.LoadFile("Path/too/app.dll")'

Comment: If you wish to get the .version using http... no way unless you created the app to provide that version inside a http header or something. And that can be done using the code in my answer to get the version, and the on every request set a header with that data.