# Find running processes targeting .NET Core 3.1

Tags: powershell, .net-core, .net-6.0, powershell-5.0

With the upcoming deprecation of .NET Core 3.1, we wanted to see if there was a way we could locate any "missed" products that may be running .NET Core 3.1 in our environments.

The environments these would be on would be Windows Servers running PS 5 or later, but not 7. The machines would all have 3.1 and 6.0 installed, as well as Framework 4.8.

We would not necessarily have Sysinternals already on these computers, but I could use a component from that if it can make this work.

Some of the computers may be running IIS related code with a NoManagedCode app pool, so would not be exes.

In all cases, I can definitively restrict the search paths for where these programs would be installed to. Anything outside of those specific paths should throw an error if netcore31 is removed, so that is acceptable fallout. Consider `C:\path1`, `C:\Deep\path2`, `C:\Place\Where\Things\Are`. Assume I have administrative privileges, of course.

Comment: You can modify the environmental variable PSModulePath  You can change folder properties so they cannot be read and then run apps.

Comment: Can you expand on how that would be a useful way to check apps @jdweng because I'm not sure that changing any path variables would tell me the bindings of .net apps

Comment: if the app fails after disabling path, then you know it is running Core 3.1.  Uninstalling Framework 8 on machine would indicate software is using Framework 8,

Comment: Yeah, we just wanted to identify things _before_ we removed the netcore libs. I don't think, with netcore 3.1 _and_ net6 installed, that I can selectively disable the path in this way.

Answer (score 2):

The following *may* work well enough, which is based on *static analysis* of the *files* containing .NET assemblies (if the assemblies of interest are built *from source*, the assumption is that current build artifacts are present).

It relies on helper function `Get-DotNetTargetFramework` (source code below), which tries to extract target-framework information *via reflection* from files that are .NET assemblies, building on [this .NET Framework answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891621/45375).

**Caveats**:

- It requires [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) to run.
- On occasion, loading assembly files *fails* - I'm unsure what that depends on; [`.LoadFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile) is used to load the assemblies.

**Sample call**:

```bash
$workingFolder = 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\'

# Find all assemblies in the working folder's subtree that target
# .NET Core 3.1 or earlier.
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $workingFolder -Recurse -Include *.exe, *.dll |
  Get-DotNetTargetFramework |
  Where-Object { 
    $_.FrameworkType -eq 'Core' -and $_.FrameworkVersion -le [version] '3.1'
  }
```

Note:

- Matching files that aren't .NET assemblies generate *warnings*, which you can suppress with `3>$null`
- Matching files that *are* .NET assemblies, but can't be loaded, result in *non-terminating errors*, which you can suppress with `2>$null` and / or collect for later processing in, say, variable `$errs` with `-ErrorVariable errs`
- *.NET Framework* assemblies prior to v4.7.1 aren't guaranteed to have a [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription) attribute, the presence of which the code relies upon. All .NET (Core)-targeted assemblies should.

---

**`Get-DotNetTargetFramework` source code:**

```bash
function Get-DotNetTargetFramework {
  <#
.SYNOPSIS
  Outputs target framework / runtime version information for .NET assemblies.
.DESCRIPTION
  Note: Runs in PowerShell *Core* only.

  The target .NET assemblies must be specifiy by their file paths, and 
  only literal file paths are accepted, but you can pipe Get-ChildItem output
  to this command.

  Input files that aren't .NET assemblies result in a warning.
  
  Assemblies that have no target-framework information in their manifests
  were typically compiled for .NET Framework versions before v4.7.1.
  Since then, and in all .NET (Core) versions, that information should be present.
  
.EXAMPLE
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.exe, *.dll | Get-DotNetTargetFramework
  
  Outputs target framework information for all *.exe and *.dll files in the current
  directory subtree.
#>
  [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false)]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, Position = 0)]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    [string] $LiteralPath
  )
  begin {
    # !! We require running in PS Core, because NET Framework can't (easily) load .NET Core assemblies.
    if (-not $IsCoreCLR) { throw "This command runs in PowerShell (Core) only." }
  }
  process {
    $fullName = Convert-Path -LiteralPath $LiteralPath
    if (-not $?) { return }
    try {
      $assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($fullName)
      $targetFramework = $assembly.GetCustomAttributesData().Where({ $_.AttributeType -eq [System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute] }).ConstructorArguments.Value
      $versionString = if ($targetFramework -match '\d+(?:\.\d+){1,3}') { $Matches[0] }
      [pscustomobject] @{
        AssemblyFilePath     = $fullName
        FrameworkType        = ('Framework', 'Core')[$targetFramework -and $targetFramework -match '^\.NETCoreApp']
        FrameworkVersion     = $(if ($versionString) { $versionString -as [version] })
        FrameworkDescription = $(if ($targetFramework) { $targetFramework } else { '.NETFramework,Version=vPRE_4.7.1' }
      })
    }
    catch {
      if ($_.Exception.InnerException -is [System.BadImageFormatException]) {
        Write-Warning "Not a .NET assembly: '$fullName'"
      }
      elseif ($_.Exception.InnerException -is [System.IO.FileLoadException]) {
        # !! Unclear, when that happens. $_.Exception.InnerException provides NO further clues.
        Write-Error " .NET assembly that cannot be loaded: '$fullName'`n$_"
      }
      else {
        Write-Error "Unexpected error with '$fullName': $_"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with my team and a little experimentation, this is the direction we are currently leaning for solution, but I am 100% open to other suggestions on how to determine this:

```powershell
$workingFolder = 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\'

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $workingFolder | % {
    $path = $_.FullName
    $children = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter 'lib\runtimes\win\lib\' -Directory -ErrorAction Ignore
    if ($children.Count -gt 0 -and -not ($children.Name -contains 'net6.0')) { 
        $problemFolder = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'lib\runtimes\win\lib\'
        return (Get-ChildItem -Path $problemFolder -Directory) 
    }
}
```

In this case, every folder that has the subpath `lib\runtimes\win\lib` (netcore|6 apps) but that does not have a subpath under that for `net6.0` should drop some entries like this:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         4/7/2022   3:29 PM                netcoreapp2.0
d-----         4/7/2022   3:29 PM                netcoreapp2.1
d-----         4/7/2022   3:29 PM                netcoreapp3.0
d-----         4/7/2022   3:29 PM                netstandard2.0
```

Which we can see do not have a net6.0 but clearly have older runtime releated folders. The parent folders that either have *no* `lib\runtimes\win\lib` structure, or that *do have* the `lib\runtimes\win\lib\net6.0` subfolder tree, will not return on the above result set. Which is the behavior I'm seeing.

> The faulty assumption that I know I am making is that it is possible to have a net6.0 application that does not contain this runtimes folder, but I feel like the knowledge *and desire* necessary to evoke that situation is suspect, as most of my devs, while highly competent, have no desire to change these semantics and make life harder for themselves. Rogue actors may exist in the ecosystem, but I hope not. Third parties likewise may have a problem, but again, simplest path is where most folks live.

While I am quite open to other answers (begging for them), I think this is what we are going to run with for now for our team (for the purposes of others coming here also wanting a solution to this problem)

Comment: This will fail with single-file executables