# How to detect required Runtimes for Application

Tags: python, c#, c, powershell, shell

I‘m currently looking for a way with which I can detect what runtimes a Program is using and output a list of each Application using Runtime X, Y, and Z and possibly the Version of the Runtime.

Runtimes in this matter could be;
Visual C (Ver X, Y, Z)
.Net (Ver X, Y, Z)
Java (Ver X, Y, Z)

Those runtimes would be enough for this usecase.

There was a way with a WMI Class called Win32_InstalledProgramFramework but this class is sadly not useable anymore, at least on Win11.

- Target Distro is only Windows. (Win 10 LTSC 2019+)

I dont really care in which language it is, it should just solve the Issue.

I‘d really appreciate any Suggestions!

BR, Denis

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For .NET, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74710058/45375) should offer a solution. If you don't get an answer here that covers _all_ desired frameworks / runtimes, I suggest asking a separate question for each.